# Keyboard shortcuts to launch an application only works if the shortcut is on the desktop

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a .bat file with the following command:

```
cmd /c nircmd screensaver
```

Nircmd is installed absolutely fine. This works perfectly. However, in order to start it with a keyboard shortcut, the shortcut must be on my desktop. The actual file can be wherever, however the shortcut file has to be on my desktop.

I've tried it in a ton of different folders, only my desktop works. This normally wouldn't be a problem but I like my desktop really, really clean (just the recycle bin).

Comment: same thing in 7, desktop, or anywhere in the start menu.

Comment: You could use the old hold down alt and press some keys on the numpad hack to give the shortcut an empty name, then change it's icon to one of the unused (blank) ones.

Comment: Like this: http://www.777icons.com/invisible-shortcut-on-windows-desktop.htm (I don't know if it works in 8, defo did in 7 and XP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Windows Shortcuts

In any version of Windows, shortcut files with keyboard shortcuts must be placed on the desktop or – if you want to keep your desktop absolutely empty – in the

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

folder. You can even create a subfolder for shortcuts and place it all in there like

```
[...]\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Keyboard Shortcuts
```

Please note that you must **redo the keyboard shortcuts** if you move shortcut files around.

## Third Party Tools

An alternative would be to create your keyboard shortcuts with a 3rd party macro tool such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/). In this case, you don't even have to create desktop shortcuts to activate the keyboard shortcuts. And they are easier to manage: In the case of AutoHotkey, you could even print them out as a list because the commands are stored in a file that you can edit in Notepad.

Of course, if you're opposed to install any program that you can avoid, this is not for you.

Comment: Just curious, why does this happen? Also, that didn't help. I put the shortcut file there and it still won't activate.

Comment: It works here on my computer. But I have no idea why it shouldn't work on yours. I use Windows 8, too. For further troubleshooting you may want to check this older post: http://superuser.com/questions/322655/do-user-specified-shortcut-keys-for-windows-only-work-on-certain-directories?rq=1

Comment: @chipperyman573 because the shortcut data is in the actual .ink or .url file, and they all get scanned in those locations, to test is to *re-make the shortcut In that location*, not just move it there.  I had the opposite even, I had shorts just made, that worked only until the next reboot, where it was not scanned, because of location.  So remake them in your testing location, and re-boot to insure operation after boot.

Comment: Aha, making them again instead of copying worked! Thanks!