# Shortcut doesn't fully work using keys in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any possibility to use shortcuts like these:

[image]

```
shutdown /r /f /t 0
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

Using keys not mouse clicks, being hidden on the desktop or somewhere except the taskbar or start menu in Windows 10 Anniversary?

Following the @w32sh's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1046375/610149), I've tried to put these shortcuts in different locations like
 
the root `C:\` or 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\`
but these are not working in the above mentioned conditions ( could be a kind of permission problem (?) these are fully functional in Win 7 ).

Comment: Correct path would be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`  - Note the space between `Start Menu`

Comment: @w32sh indeed, my bad there is no other path without space. I've modified into the question.

Comment: Does it work if you place the shortcut in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

Comment: @w32sh In 1511 it works; as soon as I'll be able I'll try in anniversary too. Thank you, this could be the answer that I've been looking for :) I'll let you know to post it officially.

Comment: I just verified it works in 1607 as well. Let's know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the shortcut in this folder works fine here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

If it doesn't work, you may create the shortcut in the per-user path below:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

Of course, this is only a workaround but if you're the only user in your computer, the above can be a perfect solution.

Not sure why it doesn't work for `ProgramData`. But inspecting `User Shell Folder` registry paths (under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`) is a good idea.

Comment: Gracias w32sh ! I can do that as well but not so sure what to looking for on that registry path. I was thinking about a kind of permission problem because if I try to create the shortcut this is [what I get](http://i.imgur.com/SBKeuiP.jpg). I am able to copy after that the shortcut but is this fine?

Comment: Regarding the New menu, it's normal. Registry entries to check are in table #3 in this page. [Windows 10 User Shell Folders Paths](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/)

Comment: thanks; strange, I've just had a look in table #3 and the registry entries are looking like it should in my [User Shell Folders](http://i.imgur.com/i2aqjbp.jpg). These have nothing in common with folder permissions?

Comment: That's strange. Are you other able to access the files and shortcuts in the ProgramData...\Start menu folder, and the apps are shown in Start menu?

Comment: sure [here we go](http://i.imgur.com/s77DN70.jpg)

Comment: I'm stumped, then :)

Comment: yea, anyway, this is a clean install of Anniversary. The strange thing is that using the first path,  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` I can't create there the shortcut, I am able only to copy it from other place. whatever. As long as everything is working good I suppose that it's useless to bother.