# Change in Windows 10 Shortcut key behavior

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I make frequent use of the "Shortcut keys" feature of Windows to assign keys to various programs I use frequently (e.g. PuTTY, see picture) to both quickly open windows, and switch *to* that open window, if it's not in the foreground.

Following the advice in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1046261/windows-10-shortcut-keys-only-work-when-shortcut-is-on-desktop), I usually put the shortcut under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs or C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\_hotkeys

It seems this behavior as changed in a recent Windows 10 build (at least as of 1703).

Now, if the window assigned to the Shortcut key is already open, hitting the Shortcut key again (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-P) will open a *new* window, rather than switch the previously open window. This is quite annoying, and negatively impacts my work flow.

Just curious if anybody knew of a way to make it resort to the original behavior of switching back to the open window, when a window is already open, rather than opening a new window entirely.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows 10 with Creators Update (version 1703, build 10.0.15063). I set `Ctrl + Alt + R` to `cmd.exe` shortcut in the Start menu and it always brings me in the same instance of cmd. I am interested in the other behavior, i.e. I'd like each Ctrl + Alr + R press to launch a separate cmd instance.

Comment: @Palec You are correct. When I create a short cut to cmd.exe, the hotkey does indeed switch to the already opened window. But when I try it with other applications (PuTTY, Chrome, MS Paint), it uses the "open new window" behavior. Very peculiar! I may need to post the question on MS TechNet. My Win10 version is 1703, 15063.413.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a simple C# program designed to emulate the original behavior. It's not perfect, but should be sufficient for simple use cases. Please find it here:

https://github.com/Tronman100/TaskSwitcher

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first issue about the path of shortcuts of start menu--

- If you want to get to your **user-specific** Start Menu folder go to
  this path::

  `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"`
- And if you want to get to the **All Users** start menu, just use this
  instead::

  `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"`

For the second issue, you can restore the opened window with Win key shortcut. When you open putty, see the placement of the putty icon in taskbar (mean if it is 2nd or 3rd place etc.). Say if putty icon shown in 2nd position in taskbar press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: That is helpful, although it does mean retaining my muscle memory which is never easy! A way to restore or toggle the original behavior would be preferable.

Comment: The pin the shortcut in taskbar to a fixed position.